# Magnetic Link of 64bits are incorect?

Tags: grub-efi

Recently I download for one of your torrents download option a 64bits copy of Ubuntu 14.04.2:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:KRWPCX3SJUM4IMM4YF5RPHL6ANPYTQPU&dn=ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso&tr=http%3a%2f%2ftorrent.ubuntu.com%3a6969%2fannounce&tr=http%3a%2f%2fipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com%3a6969%2fannounce
```

This magnetic link was referenced as 64bits but appear to be 32bits (I dont boot a liveCD to test it), in whatever case this ISO does not have EFI support.

How should I proceed?

Comment: From where did you obtain the magnetic link?

Comment: Why would yuo even bother to use torrent in the first place, [still...](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no magnetic link in the official site. I wonder from where did you get it. A torrent file is provided at the website.

**[Click here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)** to go the official download site.
The name of the torrent is ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent.

[image: official download site]